# DNS / Sharepoint requires username and password

Tags: dns, sharepoint-2010

I have a server running Sharepoint 2010 called `dc03`.  When I enter the url: `http://dc03` in Internet Explorer, then everything is fine, and I am logged in.

I created an A DNS record pointing `intranet.domain.com` to the IP adress of `dc03`.

Now, when I enter `intranet.domain.com` I have to enter my username and password, but the site has been setup to allow anonymous users.

Comment: Is the server connected via ADSL/cable router (NAT) ? Which IP did you set for A record - local or external ?

Comment: The A record is set for internal IP adress. The intrat.domain.com is intended for use with external also. But this issue is only for internal use for now. The idea is that I would like intranett.company.com to be the same for external and internal users.

Comment: AFTER you enter username and password, you get to your site or not ?

Comment: Then I get in..

Comment: Is there a problem doing it like that? I mean having the internal DNS server pointing to the LAN IP address. A have the same intranet.domain.com pointing to on of our external Ip address provided by our ISP?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with that. What happens when you access it just by IP ? I think it isn't DNS issue at all, looks more like it's somewhere in Sharepoint setup itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was DNS related. The intranet.company.com was pointing to the external address for some reason, even after I changed the DNS servers. So.. that will take some more investigation